# migrate a Laravel package form 4.2 to 5.0

Tags: laravel, package, laravel-5

I have developed a package for laravel 4.2, and as you night have already noticed the laravel 5.0 is just released, my package can not be installed on new laravel projects

my package's composer file looks like this:

```
 "require": {
      "php": ">=5.4.0",        
      "illuminate/support": "4.2.*",
     "zofe/rapyd" : "1.3.*"
  },
```

**Question**:
which changes should I make to my projects to make it compatible with Laravel 5  projects? and also my package needs this package https://github.com/zofe/rapyd-laravel which is not yet released for Laravel5, is it going to prevent my package to get installed properly?

Answer (score 6):

If your package relies on other laravel packages (i.e. those packages reference specific versions of Illuminate components in their composer.json files) composer will error when it finds version differences in the dependency tree that it can't resolve.

If you **must** rely on a third party package you will need to wait until that package is updated or update it yourself and submit a PR to the owner.

Otherwise you will need to make some modifications to :

- Composer.json
- The service provider

### Composer.json

All laravel components need to have a major version of 5.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",        
    "illuminate/support": "~5"
}
```

### Service Provider

Service providers have been changed. They no longer include methods that are used to register packages from Laravel 4.*

```
public function boot()
{
    // This no longer works
    $this->package('vendor/name');
}
```

Instead you define **how** the service provider will react to certain commands. For example, you have created a `config.php` for your package.

Previously the config was in a predefined location that could be found by the service provider as it knew your package was named `vendor/name`. Instead, in L5, you tell the provider where its config is.

```
public function boot() 
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/path/to/config' => config_path('mypkg.php'),
    ]);
}
```

This example deals *specifically* with a config file. The new method is more verbose but allows finer control over your packages assets, views, localisation and configuration.

The docs go into detail and can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/packages) and are a must read if you are updating packages for L5.

### Conclusion

1. You can't rely on non L5 packages
2. Update composer.json
3. Modify service providers to follow L5 format